# Bootstrap 4 validation not stopping invalid form to be sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, joomla

I have module with Ajax form to add user to group following their email (if this email exists in db); back-end is working and process de data, front-end is receiving the response.

However my bootstrap 4 form validation is buggy : it does not stop the ajax sending, wether or not the form is correct, but still has the validation tip popup.

HTML FORM

```
<form id="form-add-users" class="form-validate">
    <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">Email</span>
         </div>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user-email" aria-label="email User" required>
         <div class="input-group-append">
              <button id="btn-add-users" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="text-center" id="user-verification-tooltip"></div>
     <input type="text" value="addUser" name="post-action" style="display: none;">
     <input type="text" value="<?= $this->id; ?>" name="group-id" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

SCRIPT

```
 $("#btn-add-users").click(function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault() //Totally stops bootstrap form validation
        var form = $("#form-add-users");
        var data = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'option': 'com_ajax',
                'module': 'my_module',
                'data': data,
                'format': 'raw'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(response);
                if (response[0] == 0) {
                    console.log('ok');
                    //$('#tableUsers tr:last').after(response[2]);
                    //setForm(userVerif, userInput, userTable, true, response[1])
                } else {
                    //setForm(userVerif, userInput, userTable, false, response[1])

                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Example :

- email value = "" => Tooltip field required => Ajax still sent email
- value = "aaa" => Tooltip not valid email format => Ajax still sent
- email value = "aaa@aaa.aaa" => No tooltip => Ajax still sent

Any tip on why it fails welcome :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have configured the validation correctly, then the problem is because you've bound to the `click` of the `button` instead of the `submit` of the `form`. Try this:

```
$("#form-add-users").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let data = $(this).serialize();
  // your ajax request...
});
```